# How to render data from props in react

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching books data from json file

```
books= [{ id:'1', Name: 'abc', keywords: '['action', 'fiction']',....]
```

My react code for book js is

```
import React from 'react';
const Book = (props) => {
  const { book } = props;
  return (
    <div className="col-md-4">
      <div className="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <h5>{ book.name }</h5>
          <div className="card-text">
            <p>{ book.keywords}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How do i render data for keywords because it is now displaying as array only?
output : Book Name
         keywords: ['action', 'fiction' ]

required output: Book Name
                 keyword: action, fiction

Comment: `<p>{ book.keywords && book.keywords.join(',') }</p>`

Comment: Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: are you looking for  solution like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ya7zkv ?

Comment: @jayavel yes but i am getting error with book.keywords.map is not a function

Comment: @vineetakande I can see in your data keywords somethin glike a string :  keywords: '['action', 'fiction']' check the format once

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, you can use array.map in your books array:

Instead of:

```
<div className="card-text">
    <p>{ book.keywords}</p>
</div>
```

You can use:

```
  {this.props.books.map(book => // for each book, render...
      <div className="card-text">
        <p>{book.name}</p>
        {book.keywords.map(keyword => // for each keyword in array, render...
          <li>{keyword}</li>
        )}
      </div>
  )}
```

the result will be like:

[image]

Live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vc60xe51/).